# How to save data in variables defined in Java class using servlet and JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, session-scope

I have created a maven project in STS. In project i have 1 jsp file and 1 servlet. jsp asks user to enter user and password, and then servlet get values, displays them in HTML format. But i have 1 java class too. I want the entered data in jsp file to be stored in 2 variables defined in java class but i am unable to do so. I have tried few things but unable to understand how to do it.

HelloServlet:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public HelloServlet() {
    super();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<title>My Intro Servlet!</title>");

    out.println("<h1>Welcome " + request.getParameter("name") + " "
            + "Password: " + request.getParameter("Password") + "!</h1>");
    out.println("<p><a href = http://localhost:9080/HelloWorldWeb/Hello.jsp>"
            + "<input type = submit value = Back /></a></p>");

    String User = request.getParameter("Name");
    String Password = request.getParameter("Password");

    User user1 = new User();

    user1.setUser(request.getParameter("name"));
    user1.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));

    System.out.println(User);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
       }
}
```

User Java Class:

```
public class User {

private String user;
private String password;

public User() { 
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    }
}
```

JSP Form ONLY:

```
    form action="hello.html" method="GET"
doGet Name: <input type="text" name="name"> 
doGet Password: <input type="Password" name="Password" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

XML FIle:

```
    <display-name>HelloWorldWeb</display-name>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Hello.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>HelloServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.javavids.webapp.HelloWorldWeb.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: In user class whatever i do, i get error. Thats why its empty.

Comment: u want to send parameters from the form to the java class?

Comment: Yes i want the servlet to display the entered data as well as need to send parameters to java class.

Comment: first of all use `post` in the form method...and action give a servlet...

Comment: Okay i'll use post and in action i used "hello.html" because when i created servlet i changed the mapping url to "hello.html" instead of "HelloServlet".

Comment: cud u show ur web.xml file?

Comment: Added the XML file in original POST.

Comment: ur web.xml seems proper..now next lets c bout sending data from jsp page to ur servlet...put request.getparameter("name") in a string variable and system out it..tell me wat result u get//

Comment: Okay username was printed in console

Comment: ok now u getting ur data from jsp to servlet..next v need to get it to the java class right?small mistake in ur code..`request.getparameter("name")`..u have written `n` once in caps and another time in small letter

Comment: okay but other than the caps and small letter, code is correct? Is This line creating object of user class "User user1 = new User()"? and saving in variables declared in java class?

Comment: I havent done the way u have done anytime before..i mostly work with jsp and servlets.dats it...now in ur case ,probably u will have to import ur java file in ur servlet to use the `User` method

Comment: okay, so you dont have any idea how to do so?

Comment: nop...As i said u cud try importing ur java file in ur servlet and use the `User` method and try passing ur name and password..

Comment: no probs...if it was jsp and servelets oly i cud have helped u even better..

Comment: is ur query resolved?

Comment: no, not yet. I will test and submit the proper working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

HelloServlet:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public HelloServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String user = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("Password");

    PACKAGENAME.User.setUser(user);
    PACKAGENAME.User.setPassword(password);
    request.setAttribute("log", user);
    request.setAttribute("pass", password);
    boolean result = PACKAGENAME.User.Auth(user, password);
    System.out.println(result);

    if(result == true) {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.println();
        response.sendRedirect("Hello.jsp");
       }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

User Java Class:

```
public class User {

public static String User;
public static String Password;

public User() { 
}

public static String getUser() {
    return User;
}

public static void setUser(String user) {
    User = user;
}

public static String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public static void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}

public static boolean Auth(String user, String password){

    if(Password.equals("123456") && User.equals("mansoor")){
        System.out.println("Password: " + Password);
        return true;   
    }
    else {
        return false; 
      }  
   }
}
```

Welcome.jsp:

```
<body>
<h1>Welcome ${log}!</h1>
</body>
```

Hello.jsp:

```
<body>
<form action="HelloServlet" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"> 
Password: <input type="Password" name="Password" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet class should get called on the Submit Action. why are you doing this.

```
 form action="hello.html" method="GET"
```

Change it to

```
 form action="/servletclass" method="POST"
```

From inside the Servlet use the RequestDispatcher to forward control to hello.html

Comment: I added html.html in servlet mapping thats why i used hello.html. Whenever hello.html is called, in reality servlet is called. I did it because of a tutorial provided by my Professor.

Comment: you are talking about url mapping that is not the way it should be in reality.why are you using jsp,servlet and not any frameworks like Struts. also update the question with your web.xml

Comment: I added the xml file and i have not used the Struts framework because i have not studied it yet. I need to achieve my goal with whatever i studied in class.

Comment: please start accepting answers after your problem is resolved. So many people have assisted you here in finding a proper solution.That is the reason why there is an Accept option.

Comment: ok do you expect all of us to do all your assignments and spoon feed you.we are here just to provide suggestions you will have to find solution yourself.Nothings for free and go ahead and accept your answer nobody asked you not to do that and its very offensive to talk like this. its a comment against all the people in the SO  community who tried to help you here

Comment: You should read my question once more, and if still you are unable to come to your senses then i can't do anything about it. Your answer was 0% useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
user1.setUser(request.getParameter("name"));
    user1.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));
```

After this line try to print

```
System.out.println("Name "+user1.getUser()+"  password " +user1.getPassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

change method="get" to method="post"
and:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String passWord = request.getParameter("Password");
User user = new User();
user.setUser(name);
user.setPassword(passWord);
System.out.println(user.getUser + "----" +user.getPassword);
```

Comment: I need to store data in Java class not servlet. How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to save it to somewhere?

Comment: yes i want to save it to 2 variables defined in User.java.

Comment: when you set the variables,had been saved.if you want see it,only in runtime. another way is use jdbc and database,like mySql or oracle or jdo.

Comment: the variables are saved in servlet or are they saved in java class?